# Invalid workflow file for GitHub actions

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

So I am just trying to learn how to use github workflow actions and made this simple starter test:

```
name: Basic test push
on: 
  push:
    branches:
      - 'autoupdate'

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
         -  run: echo Test One Worked!
```

However, I get an error:

```
Invalid workflow file
You have an error in your yaml syntax on line 10'
```

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're indenting the `steps`, but it should be on the same level as `runs-on`:

```yaml
name: Basic test push

on: 
  push:
    branches:
      - 'autoupdate'

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      -  run: echo Test One Worked!
```